# KnockoutJS click binding never called

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
function UserModel() {
    self.forgeTransactions = function() {
        console.log("forgeTransaction()");
    }

    self.navigateToNew() = function {
        console.log("navigateToNew()");
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new UserModel());

<button class="btn" style="float: right" data-bind:"click: forgeTransactions">Add fake transaction</button>
```

The problem with this code is that forgeTransaction is never called whilst if i change the click binding to navigateToNew i can clearly see "navigateTwo" on the console.

Why is this happening?

Note: I can attach the entire source if needed.

Comment: Where do you define Self?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write `data-bind=` not `data-bind:`

Comment: +1. Also, your brackets are inconsistent.

`self.forgeTransactions = function()` vs `self.navigateToNew() = function`

Comment: Even though i did have a lot of typos writing the question, this typo was in the original html file.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is called `forgeTransactions` but you are attempting to call `forgeTransaction` in the button data-bind.

Comment: That was just a typo, sorry.